# jQuery assistance with hidden dropdowns

Tags: jquery, html, css

Alright friends of the WebDev community, I am just mucking around here and I am having issues getting the second div once clicked to hide the original div.

I would like to have it maintain the same dimensions and only allow one tab to be clicked and shown. I'm still rough around the edges with jQuery so any help would greatly be appreciated.

I have formatted everything inline to show all the code, Thanks in advance.

**WDH**

```
<html>

<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
$(".clickOnePara").click(function(){
    $(".divOneDropdown").slideToggle(999);
  });
});

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
$(".clickTwoPara").click(function(){
    $(".divTwoDropdown").slideToggle(999);
  });
});

</script>

<style type="text/css">

.divOneDropdown, .clickOnePara {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #E5EECC;
  border: 1px solid #C3C3C3;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  top: 5px;
}

.clickOnePara{
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
}

.divTwoDropdown, .clickTwoPara {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #E5EECC;
  border: 1px solid #C3C3C3;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  top: 5px;
}

.clickTwoPara{
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  left: 4px;
}

.divOneDropdown {
  display: none;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  top: 30px;
}

.divTwoDropdown {
  display: none;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  top: 30px;
}

#contained{
  border: black solid 2px;
  width: 800px;
  height: 600px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

#topNavs{
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

#contentDrops{
  padding-top: 20px;
}

</style>

</head>

<body>

  <div id="contained">

    <div id="topNavs">
      <p class="clickOnePara">Show/Hide Div 1</p>
      <p class="clickTwoPara">Show/Hide Div 2</p>
    </div>

    <div id="contentDrops">
      <div class="divOneDropdown">
        <p>Blah... .. . Blah... .. . Section 1</p>
      </div>

      <div class="divTwoDropdown">
        <p>Blah... .. . Blah... .. . Section 2</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".clickOnePara").click(function() {
    $(".divOneDropdown").slideToggle(999);
    if ( $(".divTwoDropdown").css("display") != "none" ) {
        $(".divTwoDropdown").slideUp(999);
    }
});

$(".clickTwoPara").click(function() {
    $(".divTwoDropdown").slideToggle(999);
    if ( $(".divOneDropdown").css("display") != "none" ) {
        $(".divOneDropdown").slideUp(999);
    }
});
```

Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/tqbMt/

Comment: I had tried this: `$(".divTwoDropdown").hide();` and `$(".divOneDropdown").hide();` respectively. I really like the flow that you have shown me @kei, Thanks !

Comment: How would I go about setting it up to have the first div visible onload ?

Comment: Thanks again @kei, I always seem to over complicate things.